# Normalizing Distributions for features in predicting

Tags: normalization, distribution

Should features used for predictions be normalized if they are highly skewed. Or should I only normalize target feature that is supposed to be predicted?

Comment: Depending on the model, you might not need to transform any of your variables. What are you doing?

Comment: @Dave I just wanted to ask in general, as I always hesitating should I fix skewness of all skewed features or only Y feature that I'm trying to predict

Comment: Without some theoretical reason to want to transform $Y$, I would hesitate to do so. For features, some models assume normal features (I think naïve Bayes does), but many do not (generalized linear models, for instance).

Answer (score 0):

The key assumption you take when you are building a model is that the training features and the test features belong to the same distribution.
Many algorithms are sensitive to subtle changes. For example, when Gradient Decent tries to find a local minima, it will be able to do so more easily if the data it is fed is normalized - with the mean and standard deviation of the training set. This will help guide Gradient Decent to achieve its goal faster.

In this case, you should normalize your training data, and retrieve the sample mean and standard deviation, then use those to normalize the testing/prediction set. With the assumption both come from the same distribution, the means of each training/prediction sets should be the same.

I recommend you review Andrew Ng's notes with examples, found here: https://github.com/cs230-stanford/cs230-code-examples

Comment: This addresses a different question than what was asked. The question concerns skewness, and taking the z-score of a skewed variable results in a variable that remains skewed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).